# Windows 10 HP Compaq Pro 6300 CPU, beeps 4 times and display wont show, and then it sound like a motorcycle

Tags: windows-10, cpu, troubleshooting

I upgraded my CPU in local service with GTX 750 Ti and Power Supply with pure voltage around 500-600 watts a year ago and it is still fine. I left my CPU for a month for new year vacation and then when I pressed the power button, the CPU beeps 4 times and display wont show, and then it sound like a motorcycle.

I brought my CPU back to local store, it says my room is too humid. I confused, I already mop the floor let it dry and put my CPU on table not on the floor. I asked the local store to clean it. After few days it beeps 4 times again after automatically restart.

I looks into tutorials and forum. They said, to do `sfc /scannow` and Memory diagnostic tool and setting off the auto restart if system broke and minimalize startup programs. I also do microsoft defender scanning. All of scanning say no problem except for Windows Resource Protection in sfc, it says:

```
Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files and successfully repaired them.
For online repairs, details are included in the CBS log file located at
windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For offline
repairs, details are included in the log file provided by the /OFFLOGFILE flag.
```

I also suspect if my landlord lower the voltage/electricity because I use ricecooker. Is low voltage cause the CPU keep crashing? For now I still type this question with my only CPU, is there any device to ensure my CPU is getting proper voltage and dry without bringing my CPU to local store again and again?

Comment: ", it says my room is too humid." is very fishy. I've run my PCs in tropical humidity with no issues

Comment: I think it translates to "I've got no clue" :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The beep codes are just one part of the troubleshooting. [HP Compaq Pro 6300-series Maintenance / Service Guide](https://%20http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c04034127) page 148 describes this symptom:

---

*Power LED flashes Red four times, once every second, followed by a two second pause, and the
computer beeps four times. (Beeps stop after fifth iteration but LEDs continue flashing.)*

**Cause**:
Power failure (power supply is overloaded).

**Solution:**

1. If equipped with a voltage selector, check that the voltage
   selector, located on the rear of the power supply (some models), is
   set to the appropriate voltage. Proper voltage setting depends on
   your region.
2. Open the access panel and ensure the power supply cable is seated
   into the connector on the system board.
3. Check if a device is causing the problem by removing ALL attached
   devices (such as hard drives or optical drives and expansion cards).
   Power on the system. If the system enters POST, then power off and
   replace one device at a time and repeat this procedure until failure
   occurs. Replace the device that is causing the failure. Continue
   adding devices one at a time to ensure all devices are functioning
   properly.
4. Replace the power supply.
5. Replace the system board.

---

As this is a power-related failure, the root cause may also be the main power circuit in the house. Power circuits are governed by local laws, and your landlord doesn't have means to control the voltage in power lines. However the main power circuit in the house or area in general may well be flaky and cause issues.

Other (*non-HP!*) sources suggest a RAM failure. The remedy for those is removing the RAMs, ensuring that both the RAM and the slots are clean and re-seating them. In the same go one could also test the RAM combs and slots one by one.

As this doesn't come from HP I consider it unlikely, but re-seating the RAM doesn't do any harm if performed correctly. Take care of proper ESD protection, don't force it - if the memory doesn't seem to go in the slot easily, it's being incorrectly inserted. If you aren't comfortable with working with hardware, I'd recommend asking from more knowledgeable person.

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry if I cant upvote yours. I went to local store today and ask whether RAM is failing. He said yesterday the RAM was too humid now the GPU is broken, so it works again after he detached the GPU but now the GPU works fine again. I also consult with local store if electricity in my room is bad, he said: "ofc its broken, look at the installation, Broco Inbow Ankle Electrical Switches with Socket is not good for your CPU" so he recommend me with UPS POWER UP STABILIZER VA. Idk if this will fix power-related failure. My dad just show me where to buy the stabilizer in online store

Comment: Uhhh... a socket is a socket, the device connected to it doesn't care if it has an on-off switch. I'm not sure how your local PC store could know the condition of power supply in your apartment - you'd need an actual electrician onsite to assess it. [IBM *operating* server room design humidity limits](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/power5?topic=preparation-temperature-humidity-design-criteria) are 20-80%, Philippines yearly average is 70-85% and PCs do work, so while it _might_ be an issue, not likely to be the biggest one. Great it's now working, and stabilizer is probably a good idea :-)